# Windows applications cannot be stopped and hangs

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port, wxwidgets

I created a program with C++ wxWidgets Framework to read data from the serial port in Windows 7.

[image]

When the program is running and clicking the Read "Baca" button, the data will show in the textbox. But aftert that,  the program cannot be stopped by clicking the Stop "Berhenti" button. Even the program hangs. How to make it stop when clicking then button and not hang the program?

```
//This is code for read serial button 
bool m_Aborted;
void SerialPortFrame::OnbtnBacaSerialClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{

m_Aborted = false;
HANDLE hComm;
hComm=CreateFileA("\\\\.\\COM4",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL );
 
BOOL Status;
DCB dcbSerialParams={0};
dcbSerialParams.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

Status=GetCommState(hComm,&dcbSerialParams);

dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;

Status=SetCommState(hComm,&dcbSerialParams);
COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts={0};
timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout=50;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;

Status=SetCommMask(hComm,EV_RXCHAR);
DWORD dwEventMask;

Status=WaitCommEvent(hComm,&dwEventMask,NULL);

char TempChar;
char SerialBuffer[256];
DWORD NoBytesRead;
int i=0;

do{
   Status=ReadFile(hComm,&TempChar,sizeof(TempChar),&NoBytesRead,NULL);
   SerialBuffer[i]=TempChar;
   wxString mystring1;
   mystring1<<SerialBuffer[i];
   txtSerial->AppendText(mystring1.c_str());
   i++;
   wxMilliSleep(300);
   wxThread::This()->Sleep(1);

  } while(!m_Aborted);
   CloseHandle(hComm);
}


//This is code for stop  
 void SerialPortFrame::OnbtnBerhentiClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
 {
    m_Aborted = true;
   Close(true);
 }
```

Comment: You have to get rid of the do {} while loop or move it to a separate thread. The GUI is in the same thread and does not update until your function ends.

Comment: Such a sample may be helpful. [Using some resources, timers and COM ports in wxWidgets](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814411/Using-some-resources-timers-and-COM-ports-in-wxWid)

Comment: I see a sample at <a href src=https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814411/Using-some-resources-timers-and-COM-ports-in-wxWid>Using some resources, timers and COM ports in wxWidgets</a> use timers to take data from serial port. Could it be simpler than that link?